# Ajax request and attributes

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, backing-beans

I am trying [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_attribute_tag.htm) which describes how to set attributes into server call and how to analyse the attributes on backing bean;

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" 
actionListener="#{userData.attributeListener}" action="result"> 
   <f:attribute name="value" value="Show Message" />                
   <f:attribute name="username" value="JSF 2.0 User" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I googled a lot but most examples show how to set attrs for synch-ed calls not the asynch-ed ones :S So my question is ... how to send attributes on server if that would be the ajax call and how to get them on backing bean (see suggestion A code snippet)?

**suggestion A :**

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" 
    actionListener="#{userData.attributeListener}" action="result"> 
       <f:ajax>
            <f:attribute/>? how to
       </f:ajax>

    </h:commandButton>
```

and if there is a good tutorial concerning to this question please do share the link :)

Thanks

Comment: What is actually the problem? In general: `f:attribute` on a command component such as `commandButton` is rarely used for this case. You should more easily use `action` attribute of the button and `f:setPropertyActionListener` to set a backing bean property or `h:inputHidden`.

Comment: @djmj the problem is to send two tags' values in one request as #{tagAValue} and #{tagBValue} in a more or less optimal way;

Comment: Or use a recent version of EL where you can just pass parameters to methods... I never needed to use constructions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just wrote a test which sets attributes out the ajax block as :

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" 
    actionListener="#{userData.callWithAttributes}" action="result"> 
       <f:attribute name="a" value="#{testa}"/>
       <f:attribute name="b" value="#{testb}"/>
       <f:ajax .../>
</h:commandButton>
```

...and on the backing bean

```
...
public void callWithAttributes(ActionEvent e){
  String a=(String) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("a");
  ...
}
...
```

Seems like it's working fine :) So attributes should be placed into event-making component block - the `h:commandButton` in this particular case...

Answer (score 0):

To set two properties in backing bean you can use `f:setPropertyActionListener`

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.method}"> 
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{testA}" target="#{bean.valueA}/>
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{testB}" target="#{bean.valueB}/>
</h:commandButton>
```

or with EL method argument support:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.method(testA, testB)}"/>
```